# Curl post multipart file to spring boot rest endpoint

Tags: spring, rest, curl, spring-boot

I am trying to post a file to a restful endpoint implemented in spring boot using Curl and it throws the following error:

```
    $ curl -v http://localhost:8081/qas/uploadCsv -X POST -F "file=@test.csv"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying ::1...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8081 (#0)
> POST /qas/uploadCsv HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 4257762
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------e16823418f4c8f54
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [155 bytes data]
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Application-Context: application:8081
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2016 14:27:42 GMT
< Connection: close
<
{ [247 bytes data]
100 4158k    0   236  100 4157k   1888  32.4M --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 32.4M{"timestamp":1460384862046,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException","message":"Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present","path":"/qas/uploadCsv"}
* Closing connection 0
```

I must be missing something basic but cannot see what it is. It is looking for the request param 'file' and am not sure how to send this through Curl.

Spring java config has following beans:

```
@Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("1000MB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("1000MB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(10000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
```

My spring boot web service is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadCsv", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/*"})
public @ResponseBody result handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
```

in the above signature it is looking for the requestParam file which correlates with the cUrl error.

```
    "status":400,"error":"Bad Request",
"exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
"message":"Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present","path":"/qas/uploadCsv"}
```

This request works in postman which submits the following request:

```
POST /qas/uploadCsv HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d62a469b-16c8-b30a-4168-7622d9695c57
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
Content-Type: 


----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

I also have a mockMvc integration test that works fine. Comparing the two (cUrl vs postman) in the cUrl there is no content disposition which contains the file param. Have looked around on google and cannot see to send this request? Any pointers

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I tried the solution in the following link

[File upload working under Jetty but not under Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698562/file-upload-working-under-jetty-but-not-under-tomcat)

Using the same cURL command above the file is null throwing the error below

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8081/qas/uploadCsv -X POST -F "file=@test.csv" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying ::1...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8081 (#0)
> POST /qas/uploadCsv HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 4257762
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------e6cd31736e52dfa2
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [155 bytes data]
100 4157k    0     0  100 4157k      0   681k  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< X-Application-Context: application:8081
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 07:23:18 GMT
< Connection: close
<
100 4157k    0     0  100 4157k      0   622k  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--     0{ [4 bytes data]
100 4158k    0   174  100 4157k     26   622k  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--     0{"timestamp":1460445797961,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.NullPointerException","message":"No message available","path":"/qas/uploadCsv"}
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: @dopatraman - I couldn't recreate this using latest version of curl/spring boot.. Could you perhaps revive this post with newer updates and possibly steps to reproduce ?

Comment: looks to me like your curl command is correct, might be a problem with the server code

Comment: I have tried your codes on spring boot 2.4.1, and there is no problem. Can you share spring boot version?

Comment: My curl version is 7.71.1, have you tried to upgrade curl version?

Comment: have you tried using the curl command which is generated by Postman ? Given that Postman is working fine, would be interesting to see the curl it generates.

Answer (score 2):

Curl **POST + Multipart**
To POST with a file, add this **-F file=@"path/to/data.txt**"

```
curl -F file=@"test.csv" http://localhost:8081/qas/uploadCsv
```

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it does not work. There's something funky with the multipart boundary

Comment: @dopatraman strange, I used the same code which you have provided and its working fine for me

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to the fact that `file` here is not a parameter. According to Spring web, a parameter is a 'query' parameter, so for example `/api?foo=bar`, `foo` is here the parameter in this request.

So in your case, Spring complains about a missing parameter `file` because it expects the request to look like `http://localhost:8081/qas/uploadCsv?file=something`.

Changing the method signature from

`handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)`

to

`handleFileUpload(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)`

should fix your issue